# regular Expression for Amount

Tags: regex

How to set the maximum price limit(e.g. £50.00) in this regular expression?

**Regular Expression:**
/^\£?[0-9]+.[0-9][0-9]?$/

**Sample Code used for testing**
Valid values:
12.55
£12.55
3.88
£0.00

Invalid values:
£12.
£12
££12
£12.445

Here I want to enforce the following rules as well.
**valid:** 50.00 (MAX)

**Invalid:** 50.99,100.00,1212221.00

How to achieve this in the above Regex?
[JSFIDDLE for this is available here](http://jsfiddle.net/d9fLe/)

Comment: Why would £12 be invalid? It is less than your maximum value of £50. (See where I'm going with this?)

Comment: Any background on why you want to enforce exactly two decimals? It seems pretty random to me - I'd prefer to just peek at the first character and use `parseFloat` - but I guess you have some necessary constraints for the input?

Comment: I enforce the format X.XX This is the reason why I made £12 as invalid. @BlotClock

Comment: @LinusGThiel System deals with Pence also. That's why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^\£?((50(\.00)?)|([0-4]?[0-9](\.[0-9]{2})))$/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s2hL7/